# Where on the screen is my UIImage?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a `UIImage` contained in a `UIImageView`.  It's set to use the `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` contentMode.  The UIImageView is the size of the screen.  The image is not, hence the scaleAspectFit mode.  What I can't figure out is, where on the screen is the UIImage?  What's it's frame?  Where does the top left of the image appear on the screen?  I can see it on the screen, but not in code.  This should be simple, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: As far as I can tell, UIImageView does not provide a way to query the actual frame of the image it is displaying.  Your best bet is probably to compute frame to use for the UIImageView by hand rather than relying on UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit.

Comment: That's fair.  I think I can make that work.  Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your UIImageView:

It will will compute the frame of the image, assuming you are using UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit.

```
- (CGRect) imageFrame
{
    float horizontalScale = self.frame.size.width / self.image.size.width;
    float verticalScale = self.frame.size.height / self.image.size.height;
    float scale = MIN(horizontalScale, verticalScale);
    float xOffset = (self.frame.size.width - self.image.size.width * scale) / 2;
    float yOffset = (self.frame.size.height - self.image.size.height * scale) / 2;
    return CGRectMake(xOffset,
                      yOffset,
                      self.image.size.width * scale,
                      self.image.size.height * scale);
}
```

What it does is works out how much you need to shrink/enlarge the UIImage to fit it in the UIImageView in each dimension, and then picks the smallest scaling factor, to ensure that the image fits in the allotted space.

With that you know the size of the UI Image, and it's easy to calculate the X, Y offset w.r.t. the containing frame.